# Did the Harvard Museum of Natural History have a sign saying a removed exhibit was "zoologically improbable and/or terrifying to small children"?

Tags: quotes, museums

This picture is circulating the internet

[image: HMNH sign behind glass]

The text on the sign reads:

> This object has been
> temporarily removed as we
> revise its facial expression,
> which was deemed zoologically improbable and/or
> terrifying to small children.

[This blog](http://newlightmanchester.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/honesty-illusion-museums/) identifies the HMNH label as the Harvard Museum of Natural History. Did they in fact put this label on their display?

Comment: I dunno', but I'd say that's a pangolin tail beside it. Could be an important clue.

Comment: it is from the Bizarre Animals exhibit at HMNH.  [Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/csdavis/sets/72157626335833539/with/5603195828/) is a link to an album containing a more full version of that image and a lot of the other signs from the exhibit.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, but as a joke.

Christina Davis and Jen Bervin created a series of them, in conjuction with poets.

Davis's [Flickr page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/csdavis/sets/72157626335833539/) explains:

> In conjunction with "Bizarre Animals" at the Harvard Museum of Natural History, Jen Bervin and I (with the instrumental and ingenious assistance of poets from Harvard and the community at large) created "This Object...." which opened on April 8, 2011. Graphic design by me.

[Jo Corbett](http://jocorbettceramics.blogspot.com.au/2011_09_01_archive.html) quotes a personal communication from Blue Magruder, Director of Communications at the Harvard Museum of Natural History (HMNH):

> Nothing was moved…there was space next to the Pangolin in the Asia gallery. That sign was written by a poet as part of an innovative art event at the Harvard Museum of Natural History.
>   More on the event here: http://www.mixbook.com/photo-books/events/bizarre-animals-2-0-5419059
>   All best, Blue"

Corbett goes on to give more context:

> Other signs in the art event included "This object was voted off the island" and "This object has been temporarily consumed", the latter placed in the open mouth of a hippopotamus. There were souvenirs to be had too ...eggs with endangered bird species written on them.

I acknowledge Corbett's blog isn't a terribly definitive source. I couldn't find direct confirmation on the HMNH site except that there was a [Bizarre Animals event](http://www.hmnh.harvard.edu/press-room/bizarre-animals.html) and that Blue Magruder is the Director of Communications and Marketing in their [phone book](https://www.directory.harvard.edu/phonebook/).